# Spring controller redirect ignores subdomain

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat

I have few applications (in fact 3) running in tomcat. One uses domain (domain.com) and other uses sub domains. And here comes the problem. Everything works good, until i use in my application from subdomain:

```
return "redirect:/dashboard";
```

The problem is that, it redirects not to subdomain.domain.com/dashboard but to domain.com/dasboard. Tomcat server.xml host config :

```
<Host name="subdomain.domain.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Context path="" docBase="subdomain"/>
</Host>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the complete URL:

```
return "redirect:http://www.domain.com/dashboard";
```

Comment: there are no other way to fix this problem? Maybe some tomcat or apache configs?

Comment: your answer not solves my problem. Because when i redirect to full url my session become lost...

Comment: Yes that happens, if your session id is saved in a cookie. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) how to share a cookie between a domain and its subdomains.

Comment: Fixed session editing config in Tomcat. `<Context sessionCookiePath="/" sessionCookieDomain="domain.com">...</Context>`